# Two form in one page php, but want to submit only one

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I have a page where I have a form for signin and an another for signup.
But when I click either on singin or signup button it's always the signup form who is sent.
Where is my error ?
PHP CODE :

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
      if ($_POST['modification'] == 1)      
      {
        alert("Signin");
      }
      if ($_POST['modification'] == 2) 
      {
        alert("Signup");
      }
    }
```

HTML CODE :

```
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="contact-form">
              <form id="connecter" name="connecter" method="post">
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input name="txtIdentifiant" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtIdentifiant" placeholder="Identifiant" required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input name="txtMotDePasse" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtMotDePasse" placeholder="Mot de passe" required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <fieldset>
                      <button type="submit" id="btnConnecter" name="btnConnecter" class="filled-button" form="connecter" value="btnConnecter">Se connecter</button>
                      <input type="hidden" name="modification" value="1" />
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="contact-form">
              <form id="inscrire" name="inscrire" method="post">
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input name="txtPrenom" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPrenom" placeholder="Prénom" required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input name="txtNom" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNom" placeholder="Nom" required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>

                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input name="txtGSM" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtGSM" placeholder="Numéro de GSM" required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input name="txtAdresseMail" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAdresseMail" placeholder="Email" required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input name="txtIdentifiantInscription" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtIdentifiantInscription" placeholder="Identifiant" required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input name="txtMotDePasseInscription" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtMotDePasseInscription" placeholder="Mot de passe" required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <fieldset>
                      <button type="submit" id="btnCreerCompte" name="btnCreerCompte" class="filled-button" form="inscrire" value="btnCreerCompte">S'inscrire</button>
                      <input type="hidden" name="modification" value="2"/>
                    </fieldset>       
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

AJAX CODE :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#btnConnecter').on('click',function(e){
   //prevent submitting form
   e.preventDefault();
  
   //Get Input Values
   var identifiant = document.getElementById("txtIdentifiant").value;
   var motDePasse = document.getElementById("txtMotDePasse").value;
   

   //Form Validation
   if (identifiant && motDePasse)
   {
             //Call Ajax to check if user existed
            $.ajax({ 
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "check-signin.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: 
            {
              identifiant: identifiant, motDePasse: motDePasse
            },           
            success:function(result) 
            {
               // alert(result.msg);
               if (result.msg == "Success")
               {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //Submit form if user not existed
                    $('form').submit(); 
                    //alert("Ajax ok");
               }
               else if (result.msg == "Failed")
               {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Identifiant/Mot de passe incorrect");
                    //C'est chaud
                    document.getElementById("txtIdentifiant").focus();
                    return false;
               }
               else if (result.msg == "Active")
               {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Veuillez activer votre compte");
                    document.getElementById("txtIdentifiant").focus();
                    return false;
               }
               
            }
            });
   }
   else
   {
      alert("Veuillez remplir tout les champs");
      return false;
   }
});
  </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btnCreerCompte').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  
   var prenom = document.getElementById("txtPrenom").value;
   var nom = document.getElementById("txtNom").value;
   var mail = document.getElementById("txtAdresseMail").value;
   var numGSM = document.getElementById("txtGSM").value;
   var minGSM = document.getElementById("txtGSM").length;
   var identifiant = document.getElementById("txtIdentifiantInscription").value;
   var motDePasse = document.getElementById("txtMotDePasseInscription").value;
   
   if (prenom && nom && mail && numGSM && identifiant && motDePasse)
   {
        if (isNaN(numGSM) || numGSM.length < 7)
        {
           alert("Numéro de gsm non valide");
           //Phone number invalid
           document.getElementById("txtGSM").focus();
           return false;
        }
        else if (validateEmail(mail))
        {
            $.ajax({ 
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "check-user.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
             identifiant: identifiant
             },           
            success:function(result) 
            {
               if (result.msg == "Success")
               {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('form').submit(); 
               }
               else if (result.msg == "Failed")
               {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Identifiant déjà existant");
                    document.getElementById("txtIdentifiantInscription").focus();
                    return false;
               }
            }
            });
       }
       else 
       {
            alert("Adresse mail incorrecte");
            document.getElementById("txtAdresseMail").focus();
            return false;
       }
   }
   else
   {
      alert("Veuillez remplir tout les champs");
      return false;
   }
});
</script>
```

Is it Ajax that break the php submit ?
Because I have the double form in the client section where he can change either his information or his password, and it work over there, I don't know why here it won't work :(
Thank you guys !

Comment: why are your javascript functions in two seperate <script type="text/javascript"> tags? Place entire code under single <script type="text/javascript"> tag

Comment: Neither of your `$.ajax()` calls send the `modification` parameter, so `$_POST['modification']` doesn't exist.

Comment: You can't call `alert()` from PHP, it's a JavaScript function.

Comment: @Yeak Yes i know it's a bad habit of mine ...

Comment: @Barmar Where do i need to call it ? 
And i have a " include("fonctions.php"); " in my <?php ?> where I have create a alert function

Comment: What does the PHP alert function do? It can't echo JavaScript, because the AJAX call is expecting JSON to be returned. Anyway, that's not really relevant to the problem, which is that you haven't put `modification: 1` or `modification: 2` in the `data:` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use button type="submit":

```
Update to:
<button id="btnCreerCompte" name="btnCreerCompte" class="filled-button" form="inscrire" value="btnCreerCompte">S'inscrire</button>
or:
<input type="button" value="S'inscrire" onclick="submitFormCreerCompte()">
And in the scripts create function "submitFormCreerCompte()" and call ajax to submit form
```

Answer (score 0):

So I test one or two things, and I somehow make it work like this :

HTML CODE :

```
     <button type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="filled-button" form="connecter" value="btnConnecter">Se connecter</button>
     <input type="hidden" name="btn" value="btnConnecter" />
     <button type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="filled-button" form="inscrire" value="btnCreerCompte">S'inscrire</button>
     <input type="hidden" name="btn" value="btnCreerCompte"/>
```

PHP CODE :

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
  if ($_POST['btn'] == 'btnConnecter')      
  {
    alert("Je suis dedans co");
  }
  else if ($_POST['btn'] == 'btnCreerCompte') 
  {
    alert("Je suis dedans ins");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Rien fonctionne");
  }
}
```

Thank for the attention guys

Comment: How is that fixing it? You're not sending the `btn` value in the `$.ajax()` calls.

Comment: I won't lie, I don't know, but when i click fill the signin input and click on the signin button it will log me in and when i fill the sign up form and click on the sign up button, it correctly sign up and the account is in my db

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX code is being executed?

Comment: Yep nvm i'm dumb asf, the ajax isn't executed

Comment: I tried to put modification : 1 and modification : 2 but ajax still doesn't execute

Comment: If the ajax isn't executing, it doesn't matter what you put into it. You need to figure out why it's not executing. Check for syntax errors in the console.